# postgres - CASE evaluates any subexpression that is not needed to determine the result

Tags: postgresql, case

I have the following 3 examples of case expressions in postgres, which I would expect to evaluate in the same way. However the first and the third give ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "2017,7". The second one seems to be ok. Why is the difference?

Postgres [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/static/functions-conditional.html) states

> "A CASE expression does not evaluate any subexpressions that are not
>   needed to determine the result."

```
select case when 0 = 0 then 1 < 2
        when 0 = 2 then ('2017.7')::bigint > 2000
    end
```

[(DB Fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mGWNNx7Q9FU7gZWPrp9ceR/1)

```
select case when 0 = 0 then 1 < 2
        when 0 = 2 then 2000 = ('2017.7'||'')::bigint 
    end
```

[(DB Fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ck7d7rXa6Jyyyi4XJtMRRQ/1)

```
select case when (array[1,2])[1] =1 then 1 < 2
        when (array[1,2])[1] = 2 then 2000 = ('2017.7'||'')::bigint 
    end
```

[(DB Fiddle)](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64Wgyfe2j73gpMPex5ECrX/1)

Comment: I believe there are internal optimizers in Postgres that decide which part should be compiled and checked. If you switch the WHEN conditions in the second one you'll get an error as well. Additionally in the first query you have a comma as decimal separator instead of a dot.